# Android: Displaying a typed letter as a set of points

Tags: android

I want to make an app where a typed letter is redrawn (in animation).
I already have code to animate lines between a set of points:

```
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

But how do I display a *typed* letter as a set of points (coordinates in drawPath)?

Comment: I think a feasible option will be to pre-define a point set for each alphabet.

Comment: But how would I do that?